# Как заменить do на while и print на echo?

Tags: php

```
<?php
if (!isset($id)) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,title FROM articles");
    $myrow  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    do {
        printf("<p><a href='edit_article.php?id=%s'>%s</a></p>", $myrow['id'], $myrow['title']);
    } while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
} else {
    print <<<HERE
   <form method="POST" name="form1" action="update_article.php">
        <p><label>Mətnin başlığını daxil et:<br/>
            <input name="title" value="$myrow[title]" id="title" type="text" size="30"></input>
        </label></p>
        <p><label>Meta teq daxil et:<br/>
            <input name="meta_d" value="$myrow[meta_d]" id="meta_d" type="text" size="30"></input>
        </label></p>
        <p><label>Acar soz daxil et:<br/>
            <input name="meta_k" value="$myrow[meta_k]" id="meta_k" type="text" size="30"></input>
        </label></p>
        <p>
            <input name="id" type="hidden" value="myrow[id]"></input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Bazaya elave et"></input>
        </p>
    </form>
HERE;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = '';
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $html .= '<p><a href="edit_article.php?id='.$myrow['id'].'">'.$myrow['title'].'</a></p>';
}
echo $html;
```